# Numbers at a flower-like circles

Tags: pattern, visual, no-computers, formation-of-numbers

[image]

Above picture is a flower-like circles with digits to each intersection which follow the rules:

- A circle and its center must contain all of the digits from 1 to 7.
- I have put some numbers to some letters there.

Circle example :

[image]

There are only 2  answers, find the answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First

> The middle must be $7$, as the outside is all given as $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Then

> The innermost circle (around the $7$) could be a rotation by two positions of the outermost circle in either direction, with the remaining six entries (the big inner circle, near the outside) a "rotation" by two positions in the other direction (see below).
>  The other option that one might want to try is to have the innermost circle opposing the outside one (or rotated by $3$), but the big inner circle wont work in that configuration.

Like this:

> [image: one solution]
>  or
>  [image: the other solution]